# how to select from client model all clients thats make an order orderby Count of purchase

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to select from client model all client **without duplicate client** and order them by count of the purchases they already did

This is model of client :

```
public class Client
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FacebookName { get; set; }
    public string RealName { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public int RegionID { get; set; }
    public string Addressdetails { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DateOfStart { get; set; }
    
    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Order> order { get; set; }
}
```

this is Order model :

```
public class Order
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ShippingID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SharepointID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CallStatuID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ShippingStatuID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ShippingStatuReasonsID { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
   // public int OrderStatusID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal>  ShippingCost { get; set; }
    public string purchasetype { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Discount { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool Prepared { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool Done { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool Shipe { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool Collected { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public Nullable<DateTime> DateOfCall { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public Nullable<DateTime> StockCheckDate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public Nullable<DateTime> ShippingDate { get; set; }

    public virtual List<OrderDetail> orderdetails { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    public virtual Shipping shipping { get; set; }
    public virtual Sharepoint sharepoint { get; set; }
    public virtual CallStatu callStatu { get; set; }
    public virtual ShippingStatu ShippingStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual ShippingStatuReason ShippingStatuReasons { get; set; }

}
```

and finally this is OrderDetails model:

```
public class OrderDetail
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ItemID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SizeID { get; set; }
    public int ColorID { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    
    public Nullable<int> StockStatuID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> StockStatuReasonsID { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public virtual Order order { get; set; }
    public virtual Item item { get; set; }
    public virtual Size size { get; set; }
    public virtual Colors Colors { get; set; }
    
    public virtual StockStatu stockStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual StockStatuReason StockStatuReasons { get; set; }

}
```

I tried this way but it the select is repeat Clients If they make more than one purchase:

```
public JsonResult TopClientCount()
    {
        var index = (from dex in db.Clients
                     join O in db.Orders on dex.ID equals O.ClientID 
                     select new
                     {
                         RealName = dex.RealName,
                         FacebookName = dex.FacebookName,
                         GovernorateName = dex.Region.governorate.GovernorateName,
                         RegionName = dex.Region.RegionName,
                         OrderCount = O.orderdetails.Count()
                     }).AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(o => o.OrderCount)
                     .Distinct()
                    .ToList();
        return Json(index, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use let statement and you can use navigation properties i.e (order ,orderdetails) instead of joins

```
var index = (from dex in db.Clients
                //This will give you all the order details for a client
                let orderDetails = dex.order.SelectMany(p=> p.orderdetails)
                     select new
                     {
                         RealName = dex.RealName,
                         FacebookName = dex.FacebookName,
                         GovernorateName = dex.Region.governorate.GovernorateName,
                         RegionName = dex.Region.RegionName,
                         OrderCount = orderDetails.Count()
                     }).AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(o => o.OrderCount)
                     .Distinct()
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: what if i want to select top Client According sum of thim total ?